# Fedora 29: not reading changes in .bash_profile

Tags: shell, fedora, bash-profile

I have added some aliases and functions to the .bash_profile but they are not available when I start a new Command Line Prompt. Neither they are available after a reboot.
I need to execute a 'source ~/.bash_profile' each time.
So, I have added into the .bashrc file the following:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
#Added source
source ~/.bash_profile
```

However now when I try to open a new shell, the window just pops up for a second and then closes. Any idea how to apply changes in .bash_profile immediately?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you add your aliases to `.bashrc`? That's the file that is sourced for interactive shells after all.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is meant to be executed while opening bash in interactive login-shell, not while opening terminal. You should make changes in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate): [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/129143)

Comment: There seems to possibly be another issue here as well. You say that the terminal closes immediately? Is your `.bash_profile` sourcing `.bashrc` (creating a loop).  In that case, just delete the sourcing that you added yourself in `.bashrc`.